# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Alternatives to retreating quickly when caught in a lightning storm when rock climbing?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/alternatives-to-retreating-quickly-when-caught-in-a-lightning-storm-when-rock-cl)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's the difference between Sport Climbing and Traditional Climbing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4635/whats-the-difference-between-sport-climbing-and-traditional-climbing)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I keep my backpack from resting directly against my back?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/how-can-i-keep-my-backpack-from-resting-directly-against-my-back)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What's the fastest and easiest way to replace an in-boom outhaul?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4607/whats-the-fastest-and-easiest-way-to-replace-an-in-boom-outhaul)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How do you dry wet socks when camping/backpacking if it's raining and the socks cannot be hung to dry outside](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/how-do-you-dry-wet-socks-when-camping-backpacking-if-its-raining-and-the-socks)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Scafell Pike ascent](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/scafell-pike-ascent)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Where can you find an online elevation profile of Tahoe Rim Trail?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4724/where-can-you-find-an-online-elevation-profile-of-tahoe-rim-trail)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What backpacking water purification techniques can be substituted safely during a city's boil order?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4729/what-backpacking-water-purification-techniques-can-be-substituted-safely-during)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Can I use satellite images as hiking maps, how?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/can-i-use-satellite-images-as-hiking-maps-how)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How do I prevent soreness due to friction when swimming?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4642/how-do-i-prevent-soreness-due-to-friction-when-swimming)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---